# What is the fastest way to compare layouts of my old and new webpage versions?

Tags: automated-testing, cross-browser-testing

I want to compare my old and new webpage design, What is the fastest way to compare layouts of my old and new webpage versions?

Comment: What have you tried so far and how long did it take you? Do you want to try to automate this process or just to use some free tool?